# Adding extra field to Joomla 3.6.4 registration page

Tags: php, database, joomla

I have a question about addign new fields in registrations form in Joomla 3.6.4.
For example I need to add two radio's to my registration page, I added them into page in `%joomla_path%\components\com_users\models\forms\registration.xml`
like :

```
<field 
            name="Group_who" 
            type="radio" 
            default="0" 
            label="Group:" 
            description=""
            required="true"
            >
                <option value="1">Alien</option>
                <option value="2">Human</option>
        </field>
```

But I don't understand where and how I can save this new value in my Joomla Database...
So can anyone help me with telling me path to file and / or function name where I can store my new fields value to DB?

P.S I am ne in Joomla modifing without any plugins / modules...
P.P.S And also I can't use some third-party extensions / modules / plugins(such as Comunity Builder and so one)

Comment: I dont understand your PS - comments: Are you saying you cannot write your own plugins, or you cannot use third party extensions? You cannot because you dont have the skills, or you dont have access? Your problem is typically solved by adding a simple user plugin based on the profile plugin in the Joomla core. Please try to clearify the restrictions you are facing.

Comment: @jonasfh I can't use third party extensions

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin I suggest you to create your own plugin to add new fields